# How to await service response?

Tags: angular, angular8

I have singltone service that has sync methos inside.

When I inject service to component:

```js
constructor(
   private reonMapLibraryService: ReonMapLibraryService
) {}
```

I can not get access to: `reonMapLibraryService.data;` because it is async function:

```js
public data: any[] = [];

get() {
   Promise.all([
      fetch(`assets/search-tree.json`, {
         cache: "no-cache",
         mode: "cors"
      }).then<SearchTreeNode>(res => res.json()) {
         this.data = res;
      }
   }
```

How to await all async functions in service to get them in component?

Now component works faster then service gets response.

So I need to use service in componnt only when all data is loaded in this service

Comment: You need to use Observables and subscribe to them

Comment: Any ways? I can create a varaible that contains result of all merged promises, if it is true O listen it from outside then I ensure that all data loaded, but what about performance?

Comment: can't you use `forkJoin` operator?

Comment: No I use promises

Comment: You currently use promises, but you should be using observables for this.

Comment: I guess your are right in this case @R.Richard. I overreacted. Should have done a background check ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this one**
**This is how u call a function**

```
load() {
const getdata = await this.component.get();
}
```

**This is how your Service should be**

```
get() {
    return this.reonMapLibraryService.getData().toPromise().then(
          data => {
    this.data = data
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

You can just **import** the JSON file from your assets folder.

```js
import * as data from 'assets/search-tree.json';
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems a rather strange way to create a remote service in my opinion.

Please have a look at [this tutorial from the documentation](https://angular.io/guide/http#requesting-data-from-server) to understand how you can create a service that makes remote calls.

Your service should become something similar to this:

```
getData() {
  // now returns an Observable of SearchTreeNode
  return this.http.get<SearchTreeNode>('assets/search-tree.json');
}
```

and then when needed you subscribe to the Observable:

```
initData() {
  this.reonMapLibraryService.getData()
    .subscribe((data: SearchTreeNode) => this.data = data);
}
```

If you still want your service to be a kind of "singleton" you can combine a [BehaiourSubject](https://www.learnrxjs.io/subjects/behaviorsubject.html) in order to manintain the same "Obervable" response and make it initialize just one time.